# Page under maintenance in NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Sometimes I need to stop my website to put it under maintenance and I use the following NGINX configuration:

```
server {
        server_name     mypage.com;
        listen          443 ssl http2;
        listen          [::]:443 ssl http2;

        root            /var/www/mypage.com/public_html/;
        index           maintenance.html;
}
```

The question is, if I access my website as follows:
`https://mypage.com`
everything works correctly and the `maintenance.html` page that I want is displayed.

The problem is when someone accesses a page within my site that is NOT the main one (for example, `https://mypage.com/contact`), which causes a page not found error.

What I want to achieve is that, in maintenance mode, any visitor of my web, accessing any subpage of it, arrives to the `maintenance.html` page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
location / {
    try_files maintenance.html
}
```

Adding this in inside the server block should do it, it will always match this location unless a more precise one is declared.

Comment: i get this message in console reloading nginx: `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf`

Comment: try_files maintenance.html $uri  ?

Answer (score 0):

Trying and trying it over and over again... I've found the solution:

```
server {
        server_name     mypage.com;
        listen          443 ssl http2;
        listen          [::]:443 ssl http2;

        root            /var/www/mypage.com/public_html/;
        index           maintenance.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /maintenance.html
        }
}
```